# Calculating proportion of variable when grouping by multiple variables with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping

I have a tibble containing columns group, account and duration with each row representing 1 event. I would like to make a nice summary table that includes the group, account, summed duration, a calculated price and finally the groups proportion of the total duration.

Reproducible sample:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
tidy_data <- structure(list(group = c("Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 3", "Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 3", "Group 4", "Group 4", "Group 2"), account = c("Account 1", "Account 2","Account 3", "Account 1", "Account 2", "Account 3", "Account 4", "Account 4", "Account 2"), duration = structure(c(146.15, 181.416666666667, 96.9, 52.2833333333333, 99.4333333333333, 334.116666666667, 16.6333333333333, 11.5666666666667, 79.5666666666667), units = "mins", class = "difftime")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), .Names = c("group","account", "duration"))
hourPrice = 25
```

Summary 1 - correctly calculates proportion, but does not include account number

```
tidy_data %>% 
    group_by(group) %>%
    summarise(total = sum(duration) %>% time_length(unit = "hour") %>% round(digits = 2),
                        price = (total*hourPrice) %>% round(digits = 0)) %>%
    mutate(prop = (price / sum(price) * 100) %>% round(digits = 0))

# A tibble: 4 × 4
    group total price  prop
    <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Group 1  3.31    83    20
2 Group 2  6.01   150    35
3 Group 3  7.18   180    42
4 Group 4  0.47    12     3
```

Summary 2 - includes account number, but fails to calculate proportion correctly

```
tidy_data %>% 
    group_by(group, account) %>%
    summarise(total = sum(duration) %>% time_length(unit = "hour") %>% round(digits = 2),
                        price = (total*hourPrice) %>% round(digits = 0)) %>%
    mutate(prop = (price / sum(price) * 100) %>% round(digits = 0))

#Source: local data frame [4 x 5]
#Groups: group [4]

    group   account total price  prop
    <chr>     <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Group 1 Account 1  3.31    83   100
2 Group 2 Account 2  6.01   150   100
3 Group 3 Account 3  7.18   180   100
4 Group 4 Account 4  0.47    12   100
```

I realise that the issue is, that due to the two groupings, summarize only works within one group in the second case. I considered doing Summary 1, and then joining the account numbers back onto the table, but it seems to me that there must be a better solution.

EDIT: The output I would like:

```
    group   account total price  prop
    <chr>     <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Group 1 Account 1  3.31    83    20
2 Group 2 Account 2  6.01   150    35
3 Group 3 Account 3  7.18   180    42
4 Group 4 Account 4  0.47    12     3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `summarise`, we use `mutate` to create the new columns in the dataset, then `slice` the first rows of each 'group', calculate the 'prop' and remove the 'duration' column

```
tidy_data %>% 
      group_by(group) %>%
      mutate(total = sum(duration) %>% 
                time_length(unit = "hour") %>%
                round(digits = 2), 
              price = (total*hourPrice) %>% 
                 round(digits = 0)) %>% 
      slice(1L) %>% 
      ungroup() %>%
      mutate(prop = (price / sum(price) * 100) %>% 
           round(digits = 0)) %>%
      select(-duration)     
# A tibble: 4 × 5
#     group   account total price  prop
#     <chr>     <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 Group 1 Account 1  3.31    83    20
# 2 Group 2 Account 2  6.01   150    35
# 3 Group 3 Account 3  7.18   180    42
# 4 Group 4 Account 4  0.47    12     3
```

Comment: That does the trick! :-) I did not know the slice command, and at first it was not intuitive to me that it would pick the first row of each group, but I like this solution.